# How do IPA files work?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

I want to submit an iOS app to the AppStore but I have made some very cool technology and I want the code to be protected, is the IPA encrypted in any way or can anyone view my code? How can I encrypt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IPA is just a zip file. Inside the IPA is your compiled app - it's encrypted. But it has to be decrypted to be used. If someone is interested then they can get a copy of your app, decrypt it and read through the **compiled** code (the machine code). You can't stop them doing this (well, only if you never release the app). People can't just read the code though. There's also no way you can prevent someone from looking at your app and going and creating their own version from scratch.

Comment: I'm not worried about the from scratch part (for now) I've spent about 2 years developing this code, I really just want to protect the algorithms I'm using.

Comment: So like on my computer I have photoshop, you're saying there is a way that I can look at photoshop's code? Or do they protect it somehow... I went into this question thinking that there would be no way to protect it because if a human can't somehow read the code, than how on earth does the computer read the code so that the software actually works... ya know?

Comment: It can be read but not as Objective C, rather as byte code so much harder to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, you could read the **byte** code for photoshop if you were inclined to do so. It isn't exactly easy reading. If the code is written in a scripting language then you might want to look into obfuscation but I'm assuming you're using Objective-C.

Comment: IF your algorithms really are that interesting then there is NO way to protect them from reverse engineering as soon as you deliver them to your customers. There are ways to hinder reversing but none are 100% effective. It actually is not THAT hard to analyse iOS specific code that was written in Objective C using tools like IDA Pro. The results of such analyse certainly are not Objective C code but especially when it comes to algorithms, its very well doable to "borrow" your intelectual property.

Comment: Please note that bytecode is not the same as machine language. Bytecode is commonly portable across processor platforms, machine language is not.

Comment: @Till, good point, I corrected the terminology in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the application binary is already encrypted by the time it gets to a user device but this is only the binary and the machine code can still be accessed.

Comment: Objective C is NOT commonly compiled to any form of bytecode but directly to ARM machine language when used on iOS devices.