# Any Ways to Protect Graphics / Sounds Data in IPA?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, ipa

So You can Download IPA and can Extract Images and Sounds and some other Stuff. So My Question is . Is There any way to Protect it so no one can extract images from IPA ? I tried googling and research but what i got to know is you can Encrypt Database.

Comment: So it seems you already have your answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do IPA files work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776268/how-do-ipa-files-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypt the images prior to putting them in the project and decrypt when used. The key is the weak point but the files will be protected from anyone simple copying  them from the ipa. The key could just be in the code or obtained dynamically from the server on first launch among other options depending on the level of security you require.

You can use Common Crypto AES encryption directly or use a library such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor).